# Makefie: target inside a if statement

Tags: if-statement, makefile, gnu-make

I try to run a target inside another target if a condition is satisfied.

Here is a MVP for my Makefile

```
val = 2

.PHONY: target1
target1:
   clear

.PHONY: target2
target2:
ifeq ($(val), 2)
    target1
else
    @echo 'wrong value'
endif
```

If I replace `target1`(inside the if statement) by `@echo 'success'` the code works properly so I guess the if statement is correct. However when running `make target2` I obtain the following error

```
make: target1: Command not found
```

Comment: `make` is trying to run the command `target1` but it isn't found anywhere in the current path.  Seems fairly straightforward, right?  Or are you expecting `make` to treat `target1` as a dependency of `target2`?

Comment: The recipe for a `make` rule is a sequence of shell commands.  You cannot trigger a `make` rule by executing the name of its target as a shell command.  If you're lucky, then an attempt to do so will have exactly the kind of failure you describe.  If you're unlucky, then some unrelated thing will happen.

Comment: You could conceivably run a sub-`make`: instead of the command in question being the target name, invoke `make`, with the target name as an argument.  For example, `$(MAKE) target1`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger awesome that is exactly what I was looking for ! I thought `make` would understand `target1` as a command since putting it on the same line as `target2` works: `target2: target1`

Comment: @fonfonx, listing `target1` on the same line with `target2` as shown has an entirely different significance.  It specifies that `target2` depends on `target1`, so that if `target1` is out of data then its rule will be run before `target2`'s.

Comment: It's slightly more than that @JohnBollinger (I know you know this but): listing `target1` as a prerequisite of `target2` means that before make checks to see if `target2` should be rebuilt, it will first check to see if `target1` needs to be rebuilt which may mean that the recipe to build `target1` will be run.  For this user's needs it seems like that's exactly what they want, and they already know what it will do (sort of), so I guess my question is.... why are they trying to put `target1` into the recipe instead?  What part of the prerequisite is not what they want?